# Filtering MySQL Database by field result

Tags: php, mysql, select, filtering

I am pulling stock data off of a trading API through a loop based on an aray of stock symbols. This spits out xml data which I then parse and input into a MySQL database for analysis later. This is an example of the fields I'm inserting into the database (I can add more):

```
$sql = "INSERT into securities (symbol, ask, ask_time, asksz)
VALUES ('$symbol', '$ask', '$ask_time','$asksz')";
```

My current query pulls all of the data and lists it in rows, entry after entry into a table:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, symbol, ask, ask_time, asksz FROM securities";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>id</th>";
        echo "<th>symbol</th>";
        echo "<th>ask</th>";
        echo "<th>ask_time</th>";
        echo "<th>asksz</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['symbol'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ask'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ask_time'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['asksz'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";
```

Is there a way to compare two separate stocks side by side? For instance, structure my query in order to pull those 4 fields only for 'AAPL', then in the same row pull the same data for 'GOOG'?

Comment: It would require that you set up an array of the stocks and then loop through that array and issue a query for each stock.

Comment: Can I insert the looped query into a single html table in order to get that side-by-side comparison?, or would I need separate html tables for each loop?

Comment: You should be able to set it up side-by-side, it is all a matter of how you spit out the results.

Comment: Thank you Jay, I'll give this a shot later.